# How to annotate the entity which "require express()" returns in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nuxt.js

Almost idiomatic code for Nuxt.js's backend entry point:

```
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = require('./app');

const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

async function start() {

  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  const {
    host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  } = nuxt.options.server;

  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  }

  app.use(nuxt.render);

  app.listen(port, host, () => {
    consola.ready({
      message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
      badge: true
    })
  })
}

start();
```

I need to rewrite it in TypeScript, herewith all types must be annotated.
Here are the multiple hardships, but in this question I'm going to make clear about `express`.

```js
import express from "express";

const application: BlackBox = express();
```

I tried to set wrong type for application to make WebStorm correct me. Unfortunately, the suggestion of WebStorm is also wrong:

[image]

The error disappeared in line 5, however none of express methods are available:

[image]

And same error for `use` method.
The reason is the `Express.Application` refers to empty interfaces:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // These open interfaces may be extended in an application-specific manner via declaration merging.
        // See for example method-override.d.ts (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/method-override/index.d.ts)
        interface Request { }
        interface Response { }
        interface Application { }
    }
}
```

I have read the comment, but I did not understand, why it was required to capsule the `express` method. If I need to declare `use`, `listen` etc. myself, for what type definitions for `express` has been written?

I give you some links to not make you to search the appropriate TypeScript typing youself.

- [@types/express typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express)
- [@types/express-serve-static-core](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-serve-static-core)

Comment: You need to import that name if you want to use it unqualified; `import express, { Application } from "express";`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe done! Simple solution! Thank you for the answer!